Redewendung in der deutschen Sprache. Spezifische Rolle des Pronomens "es"
Guten Tag!
Neulich bin ich auf die Redewendung

Mit jemandem ist nicht gut Kirschen essen.

gestoßen. Meine Frage ist: Ist es nicht richtiger folgendes zu sagen?

Mit jemandem ist nicht gut Kirschen zu essen.

Wenn "es" als Korrelat in Hauptsätzen bei "dass Sätzen" und Infinitivkonstruktionen verwendet wird, ergeben sich diese Sätze:

Es ist nicht gut, mit jemandem Kirschen zu essen.
Es ist nicht gut, dass man mit jemandem Kirschen isst.

Ich danke Ihnen im voraus!

Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort. Als Nichtmutterschprachler (Deutsch) schlage ich in vielen Grammatiken nach. In den zwei  Sätzen, die ich als Beispiel  angegeben  habe, wird das Pronomen "ES" als Vorläufer eines Infinitivsatzes oder eines dass-Satzes beschrieben. Diese Konstruktionen werden als Subjektsätze angesehen. Zum Beispiel: Es ist nicht leicht, ihn zu gewinnen oder Es ist noch nicht gewiß, dass er kommt. Die Rolle des Pronomens "ES" nimmt in der Deutschen Synthax einen weiten Raum ein. Es ist nicht immer leicht, dessen Rolle zu definieren.

Ja, in dieser festen Redewendung wird etwas altertümliche Grammatik benutzt, die sich darin über die Jahre gehalten hat. Das macht auch einen Teil des Reizes dieser Formulierung aus.
Die Alternative mit aktueller Grammatik, die du nennst, ist grammatisch richtig, aber in dieser Redewendung nicht im Gebrauch, und letztlich outet man sich damit nur als jemand, der dieses Idiom nicht richtig kennt.
Mit "es" als Korrelat sehe ich keinen direkten Zusammenhang, ich sehe da eher die Standard-Formulierung "(Adverb) zu (Infinitiv) sein".

Der VW Käfer war leicht zu reparieren.
Die Innenstadt ist mit der Straßenbahn schnell zu erreichen.
Im Dunkeln ist gut munkeln.



Mit jemandem ist nicht gut Kirschen essen.

Das ist eine feststehende Phrase. Solche Phrasen können manchmal den üblichen Grammatikregeln widersprechen. Weil es fixe Phrasen sind, sind sie dennoch korrekt. Das bedeutet aber auch, dass man das Konstruktionsmuster solcher fixen Phrasen nicht unverändert zum Bilden anderer Sätze verwenden kann.
Das Muster »Mit <Dativergänzung> ist nicht gut« kann mit nichts anderem als mit »Kirschen essen« fortgeführt werden. Lediglich die Dativergänzung ist austauschbar, solange sie eine Person bezeichnet. Daher kann man diese Konstruktion auch mit nichts anderem vergleichen.
Es besteht auch keinerlei Zusammenhang zwischen der soeben besprochenen Phrase und den beiden anderen in der Frage genannten Sätzen. Insbesondere hat das Konstruktionsmuster »Mit <Dativergänzung> ist nicht gut« überhaupt nichts mit einem Korrelat-es zu tun.
